# Reading Twitter Stream Using Twitter APIs

Tags: c#, api, twitter, http-streaming

I'm creating a service using c# to read **stream of tweets (TimeLine)** on a specific hash-tag (ex. [#ReformJO](http://twitter.com/search/realtime?src=typd&q=reformjo)), so after reading twitter APIs documentations, the most efficient way I came with is by using **[POST statuses/filter](http://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/filter)**

The question is I didn't know where to start with my code. So if there's a kind of hint or USED example to clarify this.

P.S: Im not looking for a search method with a result, what I need is a TimeLine reader for this hashtag since it's able to be expandable at any moment.

Comment: Have you looked at Tweetsharp? https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp - I've been working on a project that needs to interact with Twitter for some months now and the easiest way I found to interact with it at all has been via this library.

Comment: no, will check it now.. thanks for the quick response :)

Comment: It uses T$ templates to allow it to support future changes to the API so if the API call you need isn't there, fork/clone the code on github and have a look at the JSON templates in the Generated folder - you should be able to add a signature following that convention and create the call that you require